# How to return different type of values in single column in SQL

Tags: mysql

my database juse like this

```
dict_name  //  dict_id  //  type
    apple  //      100  // fruit
     pear  //      101  // fruit
      car  //     1000  //  tool
      bus  //     1001  //  tool
     lisp  //    22222  // other
     perl  //    22223  // other
```

I can get a single dict_name like this

```
SELECT dict_name WHERE dict_id=100 AND type=fruit
```

now I wanna get different type of dict_names by dict_id in SQL.

When I have dict_id like **100** **1000** **22222**,it return **apple**, **car**, **lisp**.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by this simple way

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(dict_name) WHERE dict_id=100 AND type=fruit
```

For each type

you can then try like this way

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(dict_name) FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY type
```

OR

Please try this again

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(dict_name)) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE dict_id IN(100,101, ..) GROUP BY type
```

Comment: But it's type is also fruit, tool, and other

Comment: You means when I have data 100, 1000, 22222. Use  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(dict_name) FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY type WHERE dict_id IN (100,1000,22222) GROUP BY type  than it will return apple, car, lisp ?

Comment: it return a lot of dict_name by single type,just like apple, apple, apple, :?

Comment: It return dict_name from single type but different value now,just like apple, pear.And I want return apple,car,list that belongs to different types, thanks a lot.

Comment: It's possible to return multiple dict_name in a single record?